# Combination Optimization in Python

Tags: python, math, optimization, combinations

I need to gather products from warehouse centers for product bundling
like this {product:quantity}
`center_a_products = {1: 8, 2: 4, 3: 12}`

Every centers has different kinds and quantities of products
like this {center:{product:quantity}} `product_quantities = {1: {1: 10, 2: 3, 3: 15}, 2: {1: 5, 2: 8, 3: 10}, 3: {1: 12, 2: 6}}`

I can only visit one center at a time but I can collect multiple product from one center.
If total quantity of some product is less than `center_a_products`, I must visit every center containing that product and collect total quantity of that product.
There are many combination meets these conditions but I need to know most efficient combination that visits the smallest number of centers

I tried this but it failed...

```
from itertools import combinations

# Define the centers
centers = [1, 2, 3]

# Define the products and quantities needed in Center A
center_a_products = {
    1: 8,
    2: 4,
    3: 12
}

# Define the products and quantities for each center
product_quantities = {
    1: {1: 10, 2: 3, 3: 15},
    2: {1: 5, 2: 8, 3: 10},
    3: {1: 12, 2: 6}
}

# Function to check if a product combination meets the requirements
def meets_requirements(combination):
    product_counts = {product: 0 for product in center_a_products.keys()}
    for center, products in combination:
        for product, quantity in products.items():
            product_counts[product] += quantity
    for product, required_quantity in center_a_products.items():
        if product_counts[product] < required_quantity:
            return False
    return True

# Find all combinations of products
combinations_to_move = []
for r in range(1, len(centers) + 1):
    for combination in combinations(zip(centers, [product_quantities[c] for c in centers]), r):
        if meets_requirements(combination):
            combinations_to_move.append(combination)

# Print the combinations
for idx, combination in enumerate(combinations_to_move, start=1):
    print(f"Combination {idx}:")
    for center, products in combination:
        for product, quantity in products.items():
            print(f"Move {quantity} units of product {product} from Center {center}")
```

I expected something like this

```
Move 8 units of product 1 from Center 1
Move 3 units of product 2 from Center 1
Move 12 units of product 3 from Center 1
Move 1 units of product 3 from Center 2
```

Comment: If the code was generated by ChatGPT, be aware that publishing such content (not only answers) [isn't allowed currently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know! I'll modify it!

Comment: I don't understand what the complication is for the example that you gave. center A is the stuff you need and the quantities are the stock in the various warehouses? FOr the example you provided ,just go to center 1 it has everything as 10>8 5>4 and 15>12. please provide a more complex example and the expected output

Comment: it sounds like you are tackling a variation of the travelling salesman problem

Comment: It's simple because it's a sample data my actual center, product, qty are much more complex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem description lends itself to solving with a [Mixed-Integer-Linear Program (MIP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming).

A convenient library for solving mixed integer problems is [`PuLP`](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/) that ships with the built-in [Coin-OR suite](https://www.google.com/search?q=coin%20or&oq=coin%20or&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIGCAEQRRg7MgYIAhAjGCcyCQgDECMYJxiKBTIJCAQQABhDGIoFMgYIBRBFGDwyBggGEEUYPDIGCAcQRRg80gEHOTQ2ajBqN6gCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and in particular the integer solver CBC.

We formulate a model that describes your problem:

```
import pulp


center_a_products = {
    1: 8,
    2: 4,
    3: 12
}

product_quantities = {
    1: {1: 10, 2: 5, 3: 15},
    2: {1: 5, 2: 8, 3: 10},
    3: {1: 12, 2: 6, 3: 20}
}

problem = pulp.LpProblem("CenterSatisfactionProblem", pulp.LpMinimize)

# Center vars are binary variables that we minimize in the objective. They indicate whether a center was visited or not
center_vars = {center: pulp.LpVariable(f"Center_{center}", cat="Binary") for center in product_quantities}
product_vars = {(center, product): pulp.LpVariable(f"Center_{center}_Product_{product}", lowBound=0, cat="Integer")
                for center in product_quantities
                for product in product_quantities[center]}


# Satisfy all demand
for product in center_a_products:
    problem += pulp.lpSum(product_vars[center, product] for center in product_quantities) == center_a_products[product]

# We can only take stuff from a center if we visit it 
# Also: can't take more stuff from a center than is in stock

for center in product_quantities:
    for product in product_quantities[center]:
        problem += product_vars[center, product] <= center_vars[center] * product_quantities[center][product]
# Minimize amount of centers visited
problem += pulp.lpSum(center_vars.values())
problem.solve()
```

Print solution:

```
for center in product_quantities:
    if center_vars[center].varValue == 1:
        for product in product_quantities[center]:
            quantity = product_vars[center, product].varValue
            if quantity > 0:
                print(f"Move {quantity} units of product {product} from center {center}")
```

Output:

```
Move 8.0 units of product 1 from center 3
Move 4.0 units of product 2 from center 3
Move 12.0 units of product 3 from center 3
```

Currently the example you provided is pretty trivial. It's easily possible to add additional constraints, but you need to provide better description of the problem and the expected output.

Translating a problem description into a linear program can take some practice. The trickiest line in this program is

```
problem += product_vars[center, product] <= center_vars[center] * product_quantities[center][product]
```

The objective minimizes `center_vars`, but the satisfaction constraint forces some of them to be 1.

To get the mindset of describing problems, rather than thinking of solutions I recommend Raymond Hettinger's excellent talk on PyCon 2019 - [Modern solvers: Problems well-defined are problems solved](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_GP9OpZPUYc&ab_channel=PyCon2019)

to install `PuLP`

```
pip install pulp
```

Comment: I truly cannot express my gratitude enough.

Your code has significantly alleviated my workload, and for that, I am immensely grateful. Your support and guidance are deeply appreciated.

Wishing you a fantastic day ahead!